# Create last day of month PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a form with a date picker which allows the user to select only the month and year.
Upon submitting the form The value it gets from the form is:

```
$the_Date = $_POST['month_Year'];
echo 'month date: '.$the_Date.'<br />';
// echos 'month date: July 2015' in this example
```

I need to use this to create 2 dates. I need the 1st of July and the 31st of July.
I can create the 1st no problems using:

```
$first_Of_Month = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('1 '.$the_Date));
```

But I don't know how to create the $last_Of_Month seeing as not all months end on the 31st. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `date()`, the value `t` returns the number of days in the month.

You can run `$last_of_month = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($the_Date));`

Comment: it was the letter 't'. Didn't know it existed. Beauty!! Thanks heaps for that!

Comment: Happy to help! :) Please check the answer as correct if this is the solution you went with! Also, reading the documentation on PHP.net is often a good start (Google is also your friend!).

Comment: I can accept in a few minutes. Yeah I did read the documentation, but only did a skim read haha!

Comment: We've all been there! Happened to me (with `date()`actually!) just yesterday. Cheers!